# What's the correct way to change a value that is imported by other modules?

Tags: python

I have my entry point script take a CLI option argument using `argsparser` and that looks something like this:

```
    import some_module

    if __name__== "__main__":
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Nemo Node.')
        parser.add_argument('-t', '--test', dest='testing', action="store_true")

        # handle CLI params and options
        # .....

        some_module.run()
```

I want the `-t` option to change a parameter `TESTING` in a config script `settings.py`, since my `some_module` uses things like :

```
from settings import TESTING
if TESTING:
   # do some testing stuff
```

Because of this `TESTING` is already imported into `some_module` by the time I handle the args, changes to `settings.py` can no longer have any effect on `some_module`.
My answer is what's the correct practice in dealing with this:

1. import `some_module` inside the `__main__` after the args have been parsed?
2. replace `TESTING` by `settings.TESTING` everywhere?
3. something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `some_module.TESTING` is set immediately after import, *that's* the value you want to update, not `settings.TESTING`.

```
import some_module

if __name__== "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Nemo Node.')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--test', dest='testing', action="store_true")

    # handle CLI params and options
    # .....

    some_module.TESTING = args.t
    some_module.run()
```

If the code using `TESTING` runs at import time as well, then you only option is to avoid importing `some_module` before you can change `settings.TESTING`. It's a bit ugly, though. Module-level globals are best thought of as read-only constants, or private implementation details of the module.

It also sounds like you are treating `settings.py` as a configuration file; you may be better off using something like `ConfigParser` to read a configuration from `settings.conf`, then passing that configuration (possibly modified based on command-line arguments) to `some_module.run()`.

Comment: I'm basing myself off the Django model for `settings.py`

Comment: However note that the Django documentation strongly discourages the modification of settings values at runtime: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime